# Unable to insert data into MS SQL Server using PHP in IIS

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

As I am new to PHP, I want to insert PHP form data that will run on IIS Server than WAMP/XAMP Server, into MS SQL Server.

I have installed all the necessary drivers for PHP to connect MS SQL Server.

The following is the simple code I tried. I am able to connect to the MS SQL Server but cannot perform any operations.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="md.php" method="post">
    <input name="empName" type="text"><br><br>
    <button name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php
$serverName = "MD\MSSQLSERVER,1433";
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$serverName;Database=CTest", "sa", "P@ssw0rd");

if($conn)
{
echo "Connection established.</br></br>";

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_REQUEST['emp_name']))
{
    $empName = $_POST['empName'];
    echo $emp_name;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO EMP_DETAILS VALUES('$empName')";
    //$params = array($empName);  
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
}

}
else
{
    echo "Connection could not be established.</br>";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The error log is also empty!

Comment: Try adding `if( $stmt === false ) { die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); }`, after `$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);` to see if database returns any errors

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` after your php starting tag `<?php` and try back again and let us know if you get any error..!

Comment: @Gvidas, I have also tried this earlier. Even now too. But didn't work. No report in error log too.

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai, I did, but no results.

Comment: @MohammedAhmedF : Are you sure that your MS SQL Credentials are correct? Try to login through `SHELL` using the same MS SQL Login credentials in order to confirm that credentials are correct..!

Comment: Also your `INSERT` Query seems to be wrong..! It should be like this `"INSERT INTO EMP_DETAILS (empName)
VALUES ('$empName')"`

Comment: What is your `EMP_DETAILS` table structure??

Comment: Let me know if it fixes your problem..! so that I can post it as answer..!

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai, the following is the simple table I have created for testing:

CREATE TABLE EMP_DETAILS
(
EMP_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
EMP_NAME VARCHAR(MAX) 
)

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai, I have also changed the query, but no effect on DB.

Comment: Post your latest query??

Comment: Change your Query to this : `"INSERT INTO EMP_DETAILS (EMP_NAME) VALUES ('$empName')"`

Comment: I changed php code as:

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$serverName = "MD\LENOVO,1433";
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$serverName;Database=CTest", "sa", "P@ssw0rd");
$empName = $_POST['empName'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO EMP_DETAILS(EMP_NAME) VALUES('$empName')";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ){die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));}
else{sqlsrv_close($conn);}}
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi,**

I guess that it is a permission problem. First check this by inserting this at the beginning of your php script.

```
echo "Server Software: ".$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']."<br>"."Server builtin account: ".exec('whoami')."<br><br>";
```

Take that user that is indicated and go to IIS Manager - Application Pool.
There you change the corresponding user and change from ApplicationPoolIdentity -> advanded settings.

You can see here what I changed to get access via IIS 7.5 to a certain ODBC DNS by changing the default values of ASP.NET 1.1:
[image: IIS 7.5 ODBC permissions for ASP.NET 1.1]

You could use SQL-Server-Authentication or Windows-Authentication.

You could then use local/system. This will make your application run under NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, which is an existing login for the sql database by default or change it to what you prefer. This is the simple way, but naturally you have to consider security too. That then needs further steps. This is only to make it work.

See here the SQL-server-side permissions as an image.
[image: Management - database permissions]

There are some other prerequisites too, which could perhaps be of importance:

Check PDO support in phpinfo(): 
"sqlsrv" should be in "enable" list.
Connection String: sqlsrv:Server=xxxxxxxxxxx;Database=cTest

PHP Manager in IIS 7.0 Goto PHP Manager ->PHP Extensions->Enable of Disable Extensions ->Disable List Enable your PHP_PDO_SQLSRV_5(xx)_nts.dll.

And it could - in combination with the php versionon you use - depend on the Microsoft Drivers:  3.1, to 2.0 dll files

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

[image: right drivers]

And - if you have to pass a firewall - open port 1433

But I guess that these prerequisites are all met in your environment, for if you get no php error output. **IIS simply hangs in a permission problem.**

**OK - I read your amendment 1**
The first thing is the question what user is indicated from your php script.

```
exec('whoami');
```

**Tell me that please , if you would be so kind. I need that for the further explanation.**

**OK - I read your amendment 2**
NT_AUTHORITY/iusr  - ahhh OK - he belongs to IIS_IUSRS group. That is a little bit strange, that IIS 7.5 runs below IUSR. But OK let me reflect a little while. ...
It is this one here

[image: IIS IUSR]

I never did that for IUSR, but let us try it out. Remember all steps for roll-back.

First go to IIS Manager, click Application Pools and please send me the screenshot of the indicated right side ( the "users"). Normally it would be ASP.NET 1.1. and not IUSR. This is highly insecure!

I need the screenshot, for something very strange seems to be set in your Application Pool identity settings.

See here my message on the try to set IUSR as identity:

[image: IUSR not allowed]
I have to reflect. Please wait a moment. There is something very strange.

**OK - I saw your screenshot and amendment 3**

IIS uses IUSR because of PDO permissions - that is OK.
So we make it from the other side of SQL Server permissions:

1 Add 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR' user to security of SQL

2 Set the server role as public or DBcreator and set the mapping of the database(membership of db_owner) which the user can access to as well

[image: SQL Management]

**Do you know where to make that?**

If not - we can try a very simple thing in DefaultAppPool settings. I'm now out of office for two hours.

You can simply try that for the first. It could run if your database permissions include NT_AUTORITY/SYSTEM, which is normally included.

You set this in advanced settings of DefaultAppPool
[image]

This could simply make it run if the SQL-Server side has these permissions - I guess that it is so.

**OK - I read your amendment 4**

---

Now set your connection string user name and password to ***NULL***

**`$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$serverName;Database=CTest", NULL, NULL)`**;

---

And change this in SQL Management:

[image: Windows and SQL Authentication]

I tried it out for SQL EXPRESS:

```
echo "Server Software: ".$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']."<br>"."Server builtin account: ".exec('whoami')."<br><br>";
$serverName = "RWTH-SAP1\SQLEXPRESS,1433";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$serverName\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master",NULL, NULL);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e;
    die("Error connecting to SQL Server");
}

echo "Connected to SQL Server\n";
```

And I tried it out for SQL Server 2008 R2

```
<?php
echo "Server Software: ".$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']."<br>"."Server builtin account: ".exec('whoami')."<br><br>";
try {
        $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=RWTH-SAP1\RWTH-SAP1,1433;Database=ECC", NULL, NULL);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected to SQL Server\n";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e;
        die("Error connecting to SQL Server");
    }


?>
```

It works in my environment with the settings that we tried out. Can you test it with the corresponding connection string too?

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$serverName\xxxxxxxx;Database=xxxx",NULL, NULL);

<?php
echo "Server Software: ".$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']."<br>"."Server builtin account: ".exec('whoami')."<br><br>";
try {
        $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=RWTH-SAP1\SQLEXPRESS;Database=", NULL, NULL);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected to SQL Server<br>";
        $sqlDB = "CREATE DATABASE testStackoverflow";
        $connSQL = $conn->exec($sqlDB);
        echo "Database Created<br>"; 
        $conn->query("use testStackoverflow");

        // sql to create table
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
        firstname VARCHAR(30) ,
        lastname VARCHAR(30)  ,
        email VARCHAR(50)     ,
        reg_date TIMESTAMP
        );";
        // use exec() because no results are returned
        $conn->exec($sql);
        echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
    }
catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e;
        die("Error connecting to SQL Server");
    }
$conn = null;
?>
```

[image: output]

[image: result in server]

[image]

**Debug is ok too. So all PDO things work.**

What is important too, is that you can change your PHP APP_POOL_ID, which is in my case:

```
_SERVER["APP_POOL_ID"]  ASP.NET 1.1
```

here:

```
_SERVER["APP_POOL_CONFIG"]  C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\ASP.NET 1.1\ASP.NET 1.1.config
```

Best regards

**Axel Arnold Bangert - Herzogenrath 2016**

Comment: I tried them. But no results. Yes, you are correct, IIS hangs in a permission problem from MS SQL.

But, I did not understand that SQL Permission Configuration part. Can you please elaborate.

Thanks.

Comment: exec('whoami'); -> nt authority\iusr

Comment: Now I am getting this error:

[18-May-2016 16:31:01 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'.' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\md.php:23
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\md.php(23): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=M...', 'sa', 'P@ssw0rd')
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\md.php on line 23

Answer (score 0):

I think i have a doubt in query .You should use
         $query = "INSERT INTO TABLENAME  (id,name) VALUES ('$id','$name')";
like this.

Comment: Thanks. My query is correct as the ID is autoincrement.